# Generalized Lagrange interpolation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, lagrange-interpolation

Find a polynomial of degree smaller than five such that:

$P(1)=2$, $P(2)=-1$, $P'(2)=-1$,$P'(1)=3$,$P''(2)=1$

I know I need to use a combination of Lagrange Interpolation and Taylor series but the notes i have a very unclear on this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how to mix these two methods =, you can always solve it the hard way, by defining $P(X)=aX^4+bX^3+cX^2+dX+e $, and write the above conditions as a system and solve in terms of $(a,b,c,d,e)$, here is what it looks like in terms of matrices :

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &1&1&1\\16&8&4&2&1\\4&3&2&1&0\\32&12&4&1&0\\48&12&2&0&0
\end{pmatrix}}_{A} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e \end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\3\\-1\\1 \end{pmatrix}}_{B}$$

Then you can compute $A^{-1}$ and then compute $A^{-1}\times B $ :

$$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-3&3&-1&-2&0.5\\20&-20&7&13&-3\\-48&48&-18&-30&6.5\\48&-48&20&29&-6\\-16&17&-8&-10&2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Finally, you get :

$$\boxed{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-9.5\\65\\-161.5\\169\\-61 \end{pmatrix} }$$

Comment: I indeed made a typo on $b$ and $c$

Comment: Even though I get the final result, is there a simpler way to get here ? (it reminds me of mixed inital conditions (Dirichlet and Neumman) for PDE problems)

Comment: The solution from the notes is (x-5)^3[-1/49 +5/343(x+2) -37/4507(x+2)^2]+(x+2)^3[1/343+18/2401(x-5)] do you know if this is the same as your answer just written differently?

Comment: My question is, how do you get a term of degree 5 with a polynom of degree less than 5 ? Moreover, you need 6 initial conditions to get a polynom of degree 5, so with the 5 conditions given, we can only get a polynom of degree 4 (if you want it to be unique)